# Using jquery.mb.YTPlayer onReady event, how to addclass to body or element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, ytplayer

I'm using [jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki) and want to make use of the onReady callback but sadly not having any success.

*The documentation on the GitHub page:*

> onReady: (function) You can pass a function that will be fired once
>   the player is ready; it will pass the YTPlayer object as parameter.

But does not provide an example for someone like me, who knows very little about JavaScript. I want to use onReady to add a class to the body, that way I can use a preloader. I'm attempted coding it myself but had no success, hopefully, you can.

*Here is my code:*

```
$(function(){
  $("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer({
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady
    }
  });
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $('body').addClass('LOADED');
  }  
});
```

*Have also tried:*

```
$(function(){
  $("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer({
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady
    }
  });
});

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  $('body').addClass('LOADED');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

onReady is an element inside an object which is assigned to the data-property html attribute. I am not sure about the function with onReady syntax. But try using like onReady: 'myFun' (or) onReady: 'myFun()'. In myFun function you can write your required logic. Checkout here as:
 `<div id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/BsekcY04xvQ',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1, onReady:'myFun()'}">My video</div>`

Comment: Thanks, but how would I then use `myFun()` in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

*Got there at the end!, working code:*

```
$(function(){
  $("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer({
    onReady: function(event) {
      $('body').addClass('LOADED');
    }    
  });
});
```